# AWS MSK with confluent schema registry

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry, aws-msk

Is it possible to use AWS MSK with confluent schema registry with docker instance? I dont need any Kafka connector or sink connector. Before publish want to use AVRO with confluent schema registry and deserialize the same during consumption. What are all the properties i need to set on confluent schema-registry docker? When i try to run i get this error java.lang.RuntimeException: No endpoints found for security protocol [PLAINTEXT]. Endpoints found in ZK. Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you please specify SR version and configuration you are defining? this will help to provide more detailed answer.

Comment: AWS Glue has its own Registry. Why do you want Confluent's?